# Как формировать запросы на сервис TK dpd api?

Tags: javascript, api

Подскажите как работать с сервисом api dpd!
По документации вообще ничего не понятно
Есть https://ws.dpd.ru/rest/geography/
Методы: isDeliveryAddress ServedForSameDay
Интеграционный модуль DPD представляет собой сбор набор веб-служб, построенных на базе технологий SOAP и REST и развернутых на серверах приложений Tomcat.
Дока для меня вообще не понятная: https://dpd.ru/dpd/integration/integration.do2
Я даже не пойму, как в постмане сделать простой запрос на их сервис, мне нужно при помощи javaScript рассчитывать стоимость доставки
Помогите разобраться!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPD использует [SOAP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), значит вы должны послать POST запрос на `https://wstest.dpd.ru/services/calculator2?wsdl` (тестовый сервер) с заголовком `Content-Type:text/xml` и телом в виде xml, примерно таким для метода `getServiceCost2` который вам собсnбвенно и нужен, чтобы посчитать стоимость:

```xml
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <getServiceCost2 xmlns="http://dpd.ru/ws/calculator/2012-03-20">
            <request xmlns="">
                <auth>
                    <clientNumber>[long]</clientNumber>
                    <clientKey>[long]</clientKey>
                </auth>
                <pickup>
                    <cityId>[long?]</cityId>
                    <index>[string?]</index>
                    <cityName>[string?]</cityName>
                    <regionCode>[int?]</regionCode>
                    <countryCode>[string?]</countryCode>
                </pickup>
                <delivery>
                    <cityId>[long?]</cityId>
                    <index>[string?]</index>
                    <cityName>[string?]</cityName>
                    <regionCode>[int?]</regionCode>
                    <countryCode>[string?]</countryCode>
                </delivery>
                <selfPickup>[boolean]</selfPickup>
                <selfDelivery>[boolean]</selfDelivery>
                <weight>[double]</weight>
                <volume>[double?]</volume>
                <serviceCode>[string?]</serviceCode>
                <pickupDate>[date?]</pickupDate>
                <maxDays>[int?]</maxDays>
                <maxCost>[double?]</maxCost>
                <declaredValue>[double?]</declaredValue>
            </request>
        </getServiceCost2>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Что означают все эти параметры (и где брать часть из них) читайте в [документации](https://www.dpd.ru/docs/ru/integration/ws-integration-guide.docx), там достаточно подробно все написано. В ответ тоже придет xml.

Параметры помеченные вопросительным знаком не обязательные.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, теперь понял про xml.
Иначе ни как нельзя с dpd работать, по rest json?

Comment: @Вася вроде как json формата у них нет. Существуют куча библиотек для упрощения работы с SOAP, плагин для jQuey, нативный клиент для PHP и пакет для NodeJs. Возможно последний работает и с клиента, но я не проверял

Comment: @Вася так же гуглятся примеры работы с SOAP через axios

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек!